# Undefined color in LaTeX code

Tags: color

I have a problem in configuration color for the TeXstudio editor, mine is (LeLaTeX) since I used `.eps` figure.

Always gives me an error (undefined color), this problem recently appeared when the new TeXstudio was downloaded and I lost the previous configuration. (Previously, all my documents are compiled normally.)

Please, check the attachment to see my configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A screenshot of 'half' code is not a good starting point.

Answer (score 5):

Most errors and warnings are caused by the class `NSP1`:

- It contains `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2012/01/01]`, but the most uptodate
  version is `2011/06/27` so far.
- Probably `NSP1.cls` was copied from `NSP.cls`, thus `NSP1.cls` contains a wrong
  `\ProvidesClass` statement, it should contain the correct name:

  ```
  \ProvidesClass{NSP1}[...]
  ```
- It has loaded package `color`, but missed option `dvipsnames`, which color definitions are used in the class color definitions.

  ```
  \RequirePackge[dvipsnames]{color}
  ```

  Then the five color errors should be resolved.
- The class does not define `\thepage`. I do not know, whether this is intentional.
- The class uses its own definition of `\caption` that is not supported by package `caption`. It depends on the redefinition, whether package `caption` can be used at all, or whether the class redefinition can be rewritten via package `caption`'s features.
- Overfull `\hbox`: Check your document. The `.log` *file* should tell an approximate line number. The objects are quite large, the box is more than 250pt too large.
- ...

Comment: Dear Heiko... NSP1 file as a supplement file (latex class) contains the color and other condition.. e.g \def\titlefont{\normalfont}
\definecolor{abstractcolor}{named}{Dandelion}
\definecolor{rulecolor}{named}{Bittersweet} it was work previosly but know not, i am sure that the problem in configuration

Comment: @M.Rafi: Please read my answer. If you load package `color` without option `dvipsnames`, then the colors `Dandelion`, `Bittersweet` are *not* defined.

Comment: Dear I did as you wrote  \usepackage[LimeGreen]{color}
\usepackage[PineGreen]{color}.. and the error is still the same

Comment: @M.Rafi: The option is called `dvipsnames`, see [grfguide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphics/grfguide.pdf).

Comment: still the same problem, and still i think the problem in configuration since i used this code before with windows XP but know the new version of Text studio with Window 7 doesn't work

Comment: OK,  thanks ,, it works now by changing the path of compile and view

Answer (score 1):

Replace `\definecolor{abstractcolor}{RGB}{178,233,188}`
`\definecolor{rulecolor}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}`
instead of `\definecolor{abstractcolor}{named}{limegreen}`
`\definecolor{rulecolor}{named}{green}`
in `NSP1.cls`
I was have the same problem.

Comment: Is this an answer or not? You should not need to do this. If you load the package correctly, those colours exist as named colours. If you don't load the package with the correct options, they are undefined.